Why if i change the value of the CSFR cookie my requests are still valid?
I'm trying to understand how CSRF protection works in spring security 6.x.
I have an angular SPA that logs in the spring boot 3.0 backend with formLogin.
I have this configuration in the SecurityConfiguration:
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository tokenRepository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
        CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
             requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
        return http.csrf((csrf) ->
                           csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                               .csrfTokenRequestHandler(requestHandler)
                               .ignoringRequestMatchers("/login", "/logout")
                   )
                   .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSourceWithCsfr()))
                   .authorizeHttpRequests(authRequest ->
                           authRequest
                                   .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                                   .permitAll()
                                   .requestMatchers("/login", "/logout")
                                   .permitAll()
                                   .anyRequest()
                                   .authenticated()
                   )
                   .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                           .successHandler((request, response, authentication) ->
                                   response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                           )
                           .failureHandler((request, response, exception) ->
                                   response.setStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value())
                           )
                           .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                           .permitAll())
                   .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                                           .clearAuthentication(true)
                                           .addLogoutHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                                               response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
                                           })
                                           .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler())
                                           .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID"))
                   .sessionManagement(sessionManager ->
                           sessionManager
                                   .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS))
                   .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                   .build();
    }

And this is my CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter
public class CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    protected static final String REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "_csrf";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME = "X-CSRF-HEADER";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME = "X-CSRF-PARAM";
    protected static final String RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

        if (token != null) {
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_HEADER_NAME, token.getHeaderName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_PARAM_NAME, token.getParameterName());
            response.setHeader(RESPONSE_TOKEN_NAME, token.getToken());
            log.info("for request: {}", request.getRequestURI());
            log.info("added token {}", token.getToken());
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}

It is properly setting and UUID with the CSRF token in the cookies of the front end and this token is sent to the server.
This is how a request looks like:

My concern is around the fact that if i change the value of the CSRF token in the frontend cookies it still works. Is this the right way to work?
I've been trying all the solutions i've found in SO and in the official documentation.

CookieCsrfTokenRepository works by sending a randomly generated cookie value with Cookie and checking that the X-XSRF-TOKEN header value matches the cookie value. it doesn't matter if the cookie value has been altered as long as values match (you can see in your screenshot that values of the cookie and the X-XSRF-TOKEN header match) I explained the logic in this answer

THanks for your answer, is getting hard for me to understand :S another rare thing that is happening is that, I log in with my angular app, i get a jsessionid, then i restart the backend and my jsessionid is still valid... do you know what is happening?

JSESSIONID gets set if there isn't one, and you will get a new one if you login (this is default behavior in order to prevent session fixation attacks).
